# Does MongoDB (v3.0) supports transactions spanning multiple documents, if those documents all reside on the same shard.?

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDB (v3.0) supports transactions spanning multiple documents, if those documents all reside on the same shard?

Comment: No transactions here. Perhaps you should explain *"What you want to do"* as opposed to *"What you think you want to do"*. You are likely talking about updating in the same collection ( or you should be considering it ) anyway, for which there are alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

In v2.2 it did not... and i am not aware that it changed in v3. So your answer is: No.

If this is a exam question of mongoDB, you're cheating right now by looking up the answer...

If this is a general question i would **not** check (X) the statement

> Does MongoDB (v3.0) supports transactions spanning multiple documents, if those documents all reside on the same shard.?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you gain sufficient [privelages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) then you will be able to [comment on any question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Also there was no need for you to state what had been commented earlier.

Comment: yes it does provide an answer... the answer is "no", it does not support transactions and user3559252 is not trying to solve a problem he has concerning mongodb like you said with your "What do you want to do" ...but the final exam in one of tengens courses... so he's not talking about updating in the same collection ;)

Comment: Sorry but this is a comment. As was the "comment" delivered beforehand *"No transactions here"* which basically means no. If you want to gain reputation then please provide real answers. This is not what an answer looks like.

Comment: i edited my answer to make it clear for people looking up the answer after they completed their exam - better now Blakes Seven ...? btw i don't care about rep just wanted to help out

Comment: This is still not an "answer". If you need to know what "answers" look like then please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5031275/blakes-seven?tab=answers), or in fact on any reputable user on this site. Pure commentary without a solution is not an answer, but a comment by definition. If you want to help, then put yourself into the category that provides "solutions" and not just commentary or critiques.

Comment: but the solution to his problem is the answer to his exam question and the solution for this problem is "do not check that field"